# How do I know if a number is negative in binary using only boolean operators?

Tags: c, arduino

I have to write code using only boolean operators such as follows to write code for a method that returns true or false if the number is negative or positive:

```
Bitwise AND (c = a & b), c has 1s in the places where both of the 
corresponding bits in a and b are 1.
Bitwise OR (c = a | b), c has 1s wherever at least one of the 
corresponding bits in a and b is 1.
Bitwise XOR (c = a ^ b), c has 1s wherever one and only one of the 
corresponding bits in a and b is 1.
Bitwise NOT (c = ~a), c is a with each bit inverted.
Right shift (c = a >> b), c is a, with each bit moved lower b places.
Left shift (c = a << b), c is a, with each bit moved higher b places.
Boolean AND (c = a && b), c is 1 if both a and b are non-zero.
Boolean OR (c = a || b), c is 1 if either a and b are non-zero.
Boolean NOT (c = !a), c is 1 only if a is 0.
```

I have to finish this:

```
int isNegativeInt(int num) {
  // something goes here
  return num;
}
```

it should return 1 if true, that means num is a negative number
it should return 0 if false, that means num is a positive number

and I have to do the same thing for what's below:

```
int isNegativeLong(long num) {
  // something goes here
  return num;
}

int isNegativeChar(char num) {
   // something goes here
  return num;
}
```

Any ideas? Anything would help, thanks!

Comment: Looks like a homework dump.  I recommend trying this exercise yourself.  You might learn something.

Comment: By checking is most significant bit is 1?

Comment: Clarify: you say in the title that you can only use Boolean operators, but then you list bitwise operators as acceptable?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Logical and bitwise operations are not the same, right? The op might have misused the "Boolean" name.

Comment: does the "less than" operator count as a boolean operator here?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out if Boolean relational operators are allowed with Boolean logical operators, or what. Or, should we disregard the title, and just assume the list?

Comment: In C, and with `int a`,  `a >> b`  is not `"Right shift (c = a >> b), c is a, with each bit moved lower b places."

Answer (score 3):

Given the assignment, I presume we are merely intended to test the high bit, perhaps assuming `int` is two’s complement. I also assume we cannot use `INT_MIN` or similar information (such as `sizeof int`) to know where the sign bit of an `int` is.

If we are allowed to use `unsigned`, then we can ascertain the high bit with `unsigned H = -1u ^ -1u >> 1;`. (This works because `-1u` is an `unsigned` value with all bits set, `-1u >> 1` has all but the high bit set, and XORing them leaves just the high bit set.)

After that, `num & H` is non-zero if and only if the high bit in `num` is set. So we can return `!!(num & H)`.

If we cannot use `unsigned` (perhaps the assignment is to write code that works for any signed integer type, not just `int`), then I expect the assignment is impossible using only the listed operators. To see this:

- All of the bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`, and `~`) operate on each bit independently, in parallel, and so they do not distinguish the high bit in any way and hence cannot be used to single out the high bit.
- The logical operators (`&&` and `||`) and `!` operate on all bits condensed to a single bit. Again, they do not distinguish the high bit in any way and hence cannot be used to single out the high bit.
- Thus, we are left with `<<` and `>>`. These do distinguish the high and low bits, as they are boundaries for shifting bits in or out. However, if a number is negative, shifting it left is undefined, and shifting it right is implementation-defined. So we cannot write strictly conforming C code that shifts a value that we do not know is negative or not.
- We could use the bitwise operators to clear various bits to produce a number we can safely shift, but, since those cannot distinguish the high bit, we cannot know when they have cleared the high bit to make the number safe for shifting. And we cannot generally know when they have **not** cleared the high bit (for example, we cannot write code that clears all bits but the high bit because, if we do not know where the high bit is, we do not know where the second highest is either).

Therefore, from the operations listed, there is none we can perform on a negative number to test its high bit.